# When pip installing scikit-learn "ld: library not found for -lc++"

Tags: python, c++, scikit-learn, osx-yosemite, libc++

I'm trying to pip install scikit-learn, but getting this error:

```
$ pip install scikit-learn

g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/svm/libsvm.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7 -llibsvm-skl -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/sklearn/svm/libsvm.so

ld: library not found for -lc++

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already successfully installed numpy and scipy.

I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite and have downloaded the newest version of XCode hoping it would fix the c-compiling problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up upgrading pip and all is well.

```
pip install -U pip
```

But Anaconda looks really cool, I will probably look into that too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to install python packages on Yosemite, I would suggest Anaconda. It is easy to update and any new packages you can install via pip. It handles all of the dependencies for you quite nicely ... and it's free. https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Comment: Anaconda looks like an awesome resource.  It seems as though the only problem was that my pip was outdated.  I will definitely be trying this out though!

Answer (score 0):

Pip install should install a pre-compiled wheel (I think), What command did you use?
If you are not too emotionally attached to your current python installation, try anaconda as Drew suggested.

Comment: Somehow this made me realize I should try to update pip, which turned out to be the problem.  Thanks so much for being the one to make that click!